# Friends list of a friend using Twitter4J

Tags: java, twitter4j

How can I obtain the friends list of a friend or follower using [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)?

Using [`getFriendsId()`](http://twitter4j.org/ja/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersMethods.html#getFriendsIDs%28long%29), I'm only able to retrieve the friend's/follower's list of that current user which is authenticated. What I want is to obtain the list of friends of a follower or friend of the authenticated user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long lCursor = -1;
IDs friendsIDs = twitter.getFriendsIDs(userID, lCursor);
System.out.println(twitter.showUser(userID).getName());
System.out.println("==========================");
do
{
  for (long i : friendsIDs.getIDs())
   {
       System.out.println("follower ID #" + i);
       System.out.println(twitter.showUser(i).getName());
   }
}while(friendsIDs.hasNext());
```

Comment: Didn't this code attack repeatedly to the API and you may be banned by exceed rate limits?

Comment: This will exceed rate limits very easily (dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting). Use getFriendsList instead of getFriendsIDs. Check my answer on this page.

Answer (score 6):

This will show the name of your friend's followers.

```
      User u1 = null ;
      long cursor = -1;
      IDs ids;
      System.out.println("Listing followers's ids.");
      do {
              ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs("username", cursor);
          for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {
              System.out.println(id);
              User user = twitter.showUser(id);
              System.out.println(user.getName());
          }
      } while ((cursor = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0);
```

Comment: Warning: there is a good chance that this will get you rate limited the first time you try it.

Comment: I don't understand why are you keeping on calling the `getFollowersIds` method. Is it for the paging of the responses?   
So the previous answer by sandeepsharat would return only a subset of all friends?

Comment: @rcompton Can't we overcome this limit issue?

Answer (score 3):

You only need to do this:

```
Twitter twitter = mTwitterApp.getTwitterInstance();
long cursor = -1;
List<User> users=twitter.getFriendsList(mTwitterApp.getUserID(), cursor);
```

Here users is a list users who are your friends(you are following them).
mTwitterApp.getUserID() is your login useris which is a long value.

Comment: this will only list the first 5000 users, as cursor value is -1.

Answer (score 1):

```
         PagableResponseList<User> friendlist= twitter.getFriendsList(user.getScreenName(), -1);

         int sizeoffreindlist= friendlist.size();

         for(int i=0;i<sizeoffreindlist;i++)
         {
             System.out.println(friendlist.get(i));
         }
```

It will provide you a list of 20 friends as the default limit is 20

Answer (score 1):

**This code works!** (without exceeding rate limits). Referred [twitter4j documentation](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersResources.html) and other answers on StackOverflow.

```
    try {
            // get friends
            long cursor = -1;
            PagableResponseList<User> pagableFollowings;
            do {
                pagableFollowings = twitter.getFriendsList(twitter.getId(), cursor);
                for (User user : pagableFollowings) {
                    listFriends.add(user); // ArrayList<User>
                }
            } while ((cursor = pagableFollowings.getNextCursor()) != 0);

            // get followers
            cursor = -1;
            PagableResponseList<User> pagableFollowers;
            do {
                pagableFollowers = twitter.getFollowersList(twitter.getId(), cursor);
                for (User user : pagableFollowers) {
                    listFollowers.add(user); // ArrayList<User>
                }
            } while ((cursor = pagableFollowers.getNextCursor()) != 0);

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            printError(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
twitter.getFollowersIDs("username", cursor);
```

http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersResources.html#getFollowersIDs-java.lang.String-long-
which returns only 5000 user not all users. Also it is limited 15 times in 15 minutes.(https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/ids)

Also, you can use,

```
twitter.getFollowersList("username", cursor);
```

http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersResources.html#getFollowersList-java.lang.String-long- which is also limited with 20 user. Also it is limited 15 times in 15 minutes for user auth, 30 times in 15 minutes for app auth (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list)

For unlimited access, you can look at https://gnip.com/  or whitelisted user access of twitter.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like get Friends List? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list

According to the docs:

> Returns a cursored collection of user objects for every user the
>   specified user is following (otherwise known as their "friends").

There is an interface for this in twitter4j.api, but I can't figure out how to use it:

```
PagableResponseList<User> getFriendsList(String screenName, long cursor) throws TwitterException;
```

Comment: Note: The URL is broken in 2018.