# Twitter api for getting friends list using access token and secret

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, twitter, access-token

My first question at StackOverFlow! Pardon me if I go wrong, my question doesn't make any sense or it hurts the community.

I have got **Twitter Access Token** and **Twitter Secret** for my Android app using OAuth.
(A big thanks to the people here)

Now I want to get the friend list for that specific user account.

I send both of them to my server application from where I need to access friends list for 
that account.

How can I get the friends list? Any library for that?

Any insight will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Twitter4J. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891984/friends-list-of-a-friend-using-twitter4j

Comment: @shazin: Thanks for your answer. I will look into it and then will come back if I need any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for best twitter sharing library from this stackoverflow link :

[Android Twitter Connectivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967625/android-twitter-connectivity/11240243#11240243)

Answer (score 0):

The [Temboo](http://temboo.com) Library makes it simple to interact with the Twitter API. Here's a link to the Friend List query you asked about:

https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Twitter/FriendsAndFollowers/GetFriendsByID/

You can interact with it in your browser and then generate the Java source code you need to embed that behavior in your app.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo).